# Strange JAXB Exception after GIT merge - SAXParseException - well-formed character data?

Tags: java, xml, git, jaxb

After doing a GIT rebase, out of nowhere, I started receiving this exception:

by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup"

The Java code simply tries to unmarshall an xml file to a jaxb object. Something like this:

```
...
 FGIXmlValidationEventCollector collector = new FGIXmlValidationEventCollector();

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
    try {
        unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(getSchema());
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(collector);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new FGIXmlException(e);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new FGIXmlException(e);
    }


public Schema getSchema() throws SAXException {
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    URL schemaLocation = getClass().getResource("/config/xsd/fgi.xsd");

    **return schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaLocation); // exception is thrown here!!!**
}
```

I'm clueless. There was no code change that justifies this. This code has worked for many years. I don't know why after some trivial git pull/rebase I ended up with this behavior. By the way, there's no apparent problem whatsoever with the XML file that I want to unmarshall. It's an UFT-8 xml file. I've even tried changing the encoding but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Guess what? The problem was due to git having inserted some merge comments in my .xsd file. It was not obvious from the error, only after running some maven clean and install to regenerate the java classes that became evident.

Comment: Next time consider posting the complete stacktrace.